# Call Jquery function inside razor's subviews

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use such an activity `$('#myModal').show();`

The original calling plugin routine is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').show();
     });
});
</script>
```

I put my code in the below section.
Here `$('#myModal').show({});` doesn't run

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "send-contact", id = "contactform1" }))
    {       
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(stResult)) 
             {                
                 <text>
                        <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
                             <h1>Modal Title</h1>
                             <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
                             <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                        </div>

                     $('#myModal').show({}); // The desired function!
                 </text>

             }
     }
```

There are 2 problems on this approach within my code

1. The **JQuery library** is located at the bottom line of the Master Page (_Layout)
   There's a **wrapper** over all the plugins inside the famous `ready()` function which is located there.
2. As an alternative way I placed the `$('#myModal').show();` inside the `JQuery.ready()` in the Wrapper which when it calls everything if it should have found the `"#myModal"` based on my conditions then it'll fire the function I desired.
   but again that won't fire.

I think this approach seems to be more logical and may be the only logical between these 2 approaches cause the first one the function isn't located in the **JQuery ready** function, and if I use another ready function here it's also wrong because of the duplicate of ready function.

Answer (score 3):

If you are including a Partial view called `Foo.cshtml` you could also create a partial view named `FooScripts.cshtml` and render that view where the rest of your scripts are getting loaded:

```
<h2>Main View</h2>

@Html.Partial("Foo")

...


@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Html.Partial("FooScripts")
}
```

Comment: Sorry that after asking the question I had to go and again after leaving this comment there would be a delay before my next comeback. I knew the subject you mentioned but didn't think of it as the solution. And maybe it could be in the correct path to the solution. So this way you mean I should place "$('#myModal').show();" in the jquery's Ready function where all the plugins are initialized. Right? Also the part the Jquery is looking for to run is a conditional part which would be hidden in the usual time: "id="myModal"". (Continued...)

Comment: after a submit happend during a "post" method and again it returned back to the view I want that JQuery's plugin take place and show the "myModal". If you could please address the issue I mentioned, if you are sure that this will work without any change let me know. A more clarified version is more appreciated. Thanks for the info +1