# jquery function, make call in aspx razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, razor

I would like to call a jquery function in razor, but i can't do it, why?

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "success", "alert("");", true);
```

It says that it's not defined...

Comment: You can't razor it's executed in the server side and jquery, in the client side

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call Jquery function inside razor's subviews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925439/call-jquery-function-inside-razors-subviews)

Comment: yes it can be, called from razor.

Comment: In razor: `<script>alert("");</script>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` is for web forms. If you want to call a JavaScript function in a Razor template, embed the call in the template.

There are many different ways to accomplish this. In this example, the view model contains a flag that is used to conditionally output a block of script to the client.

```
@model MyModel

<div>
    Some code in the view...doesn't matter
</div>

@if( MyModel.ShowSuccessAlert ){
    <script>
        alert("Success!");
    </script>
}
```